# Can you have on one form both JavaScript and jQuery scripts running?

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to run a form built-in HTML/CSS and my JavaScript works but not my jQuery.
My JavaScript works fine but jQuery doesn't. I tried to take out the JavaScript but still, it does not work.
I would like to give the code below from my jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#name_error_message").hide();
  $("#email_error_message").hide();
  $("#query_error_message").hide();
  var error_name = false;
  var error_email = false;
  var error_query = false;
  $("#name").focusout(function() {
    check_name();
  });
  $("#email").focusout(function() {
    check_email();
  });
  $("#query").focusout(function() {
    check_query();
  });

  function check_name() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    var name = $("#name").val()
    if (pattern.test(name) && name !== '') {
      $("#name_error_message").hide();
      $("#name").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #00FF00");
    } else {
      $("#name_error_message").html("Only characters allowed");
      $("#name_error_message").show();
      $("#name").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #FF4500");
      error_name = true;
    }
  }

  function check_email() {
    var pattern = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var email = $("#email").val()
    if (pattern.test(email) && email !== '') {
      $("#email_error_message").hide();
      $("#email").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #00FF00");
    } else {
      $("#email_error_message").html("Email address not valid");
      $("#email_error_message").show();
      $("#email").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #FF4500");
      error_email = true;
    }
  }

  function check_query() {
    var query = $("textarea#query").val()
    if (query !== '') {

      $("textarea#query_error_message").hide();
      $("textarea#query").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #00FF00");

    } else {
      $("textarea#query_error_message").html("Your query is not filled in");
      $("textarea#query_error_message").show();
      $("textarea#query").css("border-bottom", "3px solid #FF4500");
      error_query = true;
    }
  }
  //button submit checks 
  $("#contactform").Submit(function() {
    error_name = false;
    error_email = false;
    error_query = false;
    check_name();
    check_email();
    check_query();
    if (error_name === false && error_email === false && error_query === false) {
      alert("Thanks for your query - we will be back to you shortly");
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("Your form seems to be incorrectly filled - please review");
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

I am not sure what is wrong here - would appreciate your help.

Comment: check the console output in the browser and add the error to the question, not as a comment, but editing the question.

Comment: JavaScript (and therefore jQuery, which is written in JavaScript) is case sensitive. `Submit` is not the same as `submit`.

Comment: I do not get an error - when I click the form submit button it does not validate my form and does not display any messages on the form. It is like it is ignoring my JQUERY code. I have Submit as type in my html.

Comment: Also perhaps worth mentioning that my #query is a textarea?

Comment: In fact HereticMonkey - thank you ! This is the Submit that was the issue... Thanks !